# PHP look through every root directory for keyword

Tags: php

So I tried for some days to get this done. But I still don't have a single clue how i could build this code so it works. Maybe someone has an idea.

Goal: Automaticely iterate through the root-directory and any of it's subdirectories. If there's a directory, which matches the keyword it should be stored into an array.

I am only looking for directories, that's why there's a regex to exclude every object with a dot in it's name. Not perfect yet, but that's not a problem.

I ll post the first version of my code. Now it's just scanning the directory your handling to the function when calling it. Because all my other attempts are trash and this one at least works

```
searchformigration('/');


/* Check for related folders, that could be used for a migration */
function searchformigration($dir)
{
    $scanned_elements = scandir($dir);

    for($c = 0; $c <= (count($scanned_elements) - 1); $c++)
    {
        /* Anything but files containing a dot (hidden files, files) */
        if(preg_match('/^[^.]+$/', $scanned_elements[$c]))
        {   
            /* Checking for the keyword "Project" */
            if($scanned_elements[$c] == '*Project*')
            {
                echo $scanned_elements[$c];
                echo '</br>';
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Directories too can have `.` in their names

Comment: i know. im going for a proper regex when the function is working. Thats not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively retrieve files and folders with [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php), this will search in / for directories with 'project' in the foldername.

```
print_r(get_dirs('/','project'));


function get_dirs($path = '.', $search='') {

$dirs = array();

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), 
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    foreach ($iterator as $file) {
        if ($file->isDir())
        {

            if (strpos($file->getFileName(), $search) !== false)
            {
                $dirs[] = $file->getRealPath();
            }   
        }
    }

    return $dirs;
}
```

Comment: Have to change somethings. But works. Thanks for your answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would get all directories recursively and then grep for `Project`:

```
function searchformigration($dir) {
    $results = glob($dir, GLOB_ONLYDIR);

    foreach($results as $subdir) {
        $results = array_merge($results, searchformigration($subdir));
    }
    return $results;
}

$results = preg_grep('/Project/', searchformigration('/'));
```

You can also do this on Linux:

```
exec("find / -type d -name 'Project'", $results);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I am getting this error `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Project_Manager/config/modul/migration.php on line 39`. So its to much to get all directories at once?

Comment: Probably from the root of a server. You can increase the memory limit but may still be too much.  Added a Linux command.